# Image progress bar with an overlaid 0 to 100%

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a custom progress bar and have ran into more issues.  I have a progress bar that show an image going from full to nothing with a shadow that is red in the background.  Basically this is a normal progress bar but with a custom image, I want to add a label or something like that on to that will go from 0 to 100% in the time it takes to animate.  I tried adding counters to the animate but they do not increment like I want.  This is my animation block so far.

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, animations: {
                self.catScanE.frame = CGRect(x: 27  , y: 200, width: 320, height: 0)
            }, completion: {finished in self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "lastSegue", sender: nil)})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things about your issue:

- You need to set initial frame for catScanE before the animation.
- The destination height of catScanE is 0. Did you mean to make it go from
  large to small?

Comment: Not sure what you mean about the initial frame, currently my progress bar works.  The height is supposed to be 0, think of a silhouette that fills up.  I just wanted to add a label on top of that animation to from 0% to 100% at the same time the animation is going.

Comment: To animate label from 0% to 100%, you need to use timer instead. Create a timer with timeInterval = <your_duration>/100, and in timer tick handler, just update the label text with appropriate value.